# npm install module Error: tunneling socket error

Tags: node.js, npm, proxy

I am not able to install nodejs modules using npm on windows. I am behind a proxy and I set the proxy like this:

```
npm config set proxy internet.cp:8080
npm config set proxy-http internet.cp:8080
```

When I try to install a packet, i get this error:

```
npm info retry will retry, error on last attempt: Error: tunneling socket could not be established
```

I have some questions:

```
 - how can I make npm work with socks5
 - can I configure a proxycap file so that npm will use socks5
 - other suggestions
```

Answer (score 0):

It may be happening due to your proxy which is preventing https requests.

Try executing the below command before installing the packets.

```
npm config set registry http://registry.npmjs.org/
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: It didn't work. npm info retry will retry, error on last attempt: Error: self signed certificate chain.

Comment: Try executing `npm config set ca=null` before executing the `npm config...` command mentioned in the above answer.

Comment: It still doesn't work, I have the same error (self signed ca)

Answer (score 0):

It turned out that the proxy I used wasn't the right one. Afeter using the right proxy, and setting it with the commands above, it worked.

```
npm config set proxy internet.cp:8080
npm config set proxy-http internet.cp:8080
```